# How to check if a file is empty before start reading it if I'm using a input redirection. (Example: main < in.txt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

## **Problem**

I'm trying to check if a file is empty.

The way I'm reading the file is by

```
python3 main.py < in.txt
```

so I'm not using any import os for checking the files on the system.

Here my script

```
#File is not in yet
data=''
#Reading file until "0 0 0 0" line appears

#Any posible way to check if file comes empty here?

while (data != "0 0 0 0"):
    data=input()
    print(data)
    elements=data.split() #to separate data when ' ' comes in
print("done")
```

When the file is empty I get a `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

## **What I need**

Is there any posible way to compare the data=input() when a empty file comes in with the file size or a condition when using input redirection to read a file?

Something like

```
if ((data=input())==NULL): | if ((data=input())==''):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just catch the `EOFError`:

```
try:
    data = input()
except EOFError:
    print("file was empty")
```